# My website randomly redirects to RSS feed

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache, cpanel

While browsing the subdomain of my website (http://camiland.gorilandcomic.com/) for some reason and completely at random (it seems) you get redirected to the RSS feed page of the website (http://camiland.gorilandcomic.com/feed). This, however, doesn't happen in the main domain, even though it's the same website with the same plugins but just different content and colors.
My website was made with wordpress, apache, cpanel, html y php. Please help.

I checked the redirect section in cPanel but it's empty, so the problem is not there.

Comment: Random behaviour is rare in computing and has to be introduced intentionally most of the time. So, I think that it just seems random, but in reality isn't. There's no pattern you can discover? First things first: 1. Clear the cache of your browser. 2. Then inspect a link you intend to click on, before you click on it. And then 3. check in the network tab of your [developer tools](https://updraftplus.com/faqs/how-do-i-open-my-browsers-developer-tools/) what exactly happens.

Comment: It happens on any page while browsing with no aparent pattern. The only thing that's 100% sure is that if you F5 when you get the RSS feed page, it will show the intended page. Now that's an important detail I missed: It's not that the URL in the browser says "website.com/feed", it actually shows the intended URL in the browser but the content is from the RSS page (white background and black text) so technically it's not a redirection perse.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of idea's, better wait for a real Wordpress expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it appears to be a CORS issue with the following details.

This line here

```
<meta name="Referrer" content="" />
```

Gives an error of

```
Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'always', 'default', 'never', 'origin-when-crossorigin', 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged
```

This led me tho to the following post here:

https://moz.com/blog/meta-referrer-tag

Which explains your issue precisely and why the 'random' behavior is occurring (its not CORS after all). It is occurring whenever you refer someone to the url (ie clicking on it from stackoverflow is a referal; but not when you refresh the page as there is no referrer (ie you didn't come from a link on another site). I suspect that because of your `content=""` value not being accepted as a legitimate value (see the error message or blog article for proper values) that the browser is guessing it to be `<link rel="alternate"` which is your rss feed.

Comment: Thanks a LOT dessus! Fixed the problem on the spot! Tho, I wasn't able to find how to modify it directly in the code or cPanel, so I had to download and install the wordpress plugin "W3 Cache" and since it has an option to change the referral, it got the job done. Kinda wish I know how to change it directly tho but THANKS again Dessus!